# не могу подключить MongoDB к php

Tags: php, mongodb

Не так давно начал изучать PHP, и мне потребовалась работа с MongoDB, я ее скачал. а сведения как подключаться (и тд и тп) черпал отсюда https://metanit.com/nosql/mongodb/3.1.php , все сделал как там написано, скачал пакет php_mongodb.ini для своего php 7.3, только скачивал с PECL а не по ссылке с сайта(не работает), закинул в ext (она у меня прописана по умолчанию как папка для доп. библиотек), прописал его в php.ini, перезапускаю phpinfo() не показывает, потом долго гуглил, вроде еще пишут что нужна папка vendor которую создает composer, сделал, только что дальше с ней делать и куда ее девать не понятно. Помогите разобраться!

Answer (score 1):

После установки модулей PHP обычно рекомендуется перезапустить web-сервер (Apache или Nginx).
Composer используется для установки файлов или пакетов, написанных на PHP. С его помощью может понадобиться установить какой то пакет в приложение, которое будет взаимодействовать с БД Монго через установленный драйвер.